# Checking referenced resources with an Azure Policy

Tags: azure-policy

Lets say i have a `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products` resource named **Public** and i want to enforce a policy where only 2 API resources at `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products/apis` are allowed to reference the **Public** resource.

Is this possible? I only see examples where a single resource value is being checked, this is a problem where it's crossing resources.

I was thinking of doing the `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products[*]` iteration and then checking the api's using the `allOf` operator, but api's aren't a property value of `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products`, it's a separate resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the count feature to see how many resource reference. However, it looks like ApiManagement doesn't have any aliases so you can't use policy on it.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer as it's better than nothing.